# What is the word that describes a repetition of previous studies?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to express the act of restudying or repeating something that has been already studied. For example,

> Before you start to study statistics, it is a good idea to ... (missing verb)
>   probability theory.

Comment: Revise. Rehearse?

Comment: *go through*, *revise*?

Comment: I'd use either *refresh*, as in *...it is a good idea for you to refresh your probability theory*; or *revisit*, as in *...it is a good idea for you to revisit probability theory.* @EdwinAshworth I can't use either of yours in that sense. US/Brit thing? *Revise* is strictly a document editing word. Metaphorically, you can revise your plans, but the allusion is to blueprints. *Rehearse* doesn't apply a perusal of prerequisite materials.

Comment: @Phil 'Revise' is absolutely standard in the UK, no hint of regionalism. [Collins CoBuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/revise) does flag the sense as 'British'. 'Revise history'. 'Revise your maths' (more colloquial with 'your'). 'Revise for the test / exams next week'.

Comment: It's unknown in the US.

Comment: ...Yes; that's the consensus at [American English equivalent of 'revise' as in studying](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139918/american-english-equivalent-of-revise-as-in-studying).

Comment: As a BrE speaker, I would only use Revise in the context of *going over material taught, in readyness for a test/exam* (Along with the editing meaning). If I were to look back over something learnt in a previous year (as a reminder) though, I would use '*revisit*'  - '*This year, we will revisit Calculus*'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Review seems the more succinct and accurate verb.

Comment: "Review" in the US.  "Revise" in the UK.  See the link provided by Edwin.

Comment: Answers should be about evidence, not opinions.